# R+data.table subsetting dataset based on the combination of 3 columns and keeping only first rows

Tags: r, data.table

I have a short follow-up question to the thread:
[R subsetting dataframe based on the combination of 3 columns and excluding duplicate combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646397/r-subsetting-dataframe-based-on-the-combination-of-3-columns-and-excluding-dupli)

I have a dataset like this:

```
Experiment  Sequence    Parameter   Time
Exp1        JJJJ        2           10     *
Exp1        JJJJ        2           11     *
Exp1        JJJJ        2           12     *
Exp2        JJJJ        2           13
Exp3        JJJJ        2           15
Exp1        ZZZZ        3           12    
Exp2        ZZZZ        3           23     *
Exp2        ZZZZ        3           23.5   *
Exp2        ZZZZ        3           24     *
Exp3        ZZZZ        3           15
.....
```

Now, for every sequence, I want to keep only the 1st of the unique Experiment+Sequence+Parameter combination.
Practically, reduce the rows marked with *, to end up with a dataset like:

```
Experiment  Sequence    Parameter   Time
Exp1        JJJJ        2           10     *
Exp2        JJJJ        2           13    
Exp3        JJJJ        2           15
Exp1        ZZZZ        3           12
Exp2        ZZZZ        3           23     *
Exp3        ZZZZ        3           15
.....
```

I want to use data.table package, which is really amazing, and I came up with this solution. It takes quite some time, so I wonder if there is a better/fastest way/syntax.

```
keycols = c("Sequence","Parameter","Experiment")
setkeyv(DT,keycols) 
DT <- DT[,head(.SD,1), by = key(DT)]
```

Comment: Although it is ok to do so, there is no specific need to set the keycols beforehand. Just `DT[, head(.SD,1), by = .(Sequence, Parameter, Experiment)]` would do just fine.

Comment: I'd use `.SD[1,]` instead of `head`, but it seems that your approach is right.

Comment: @Beginner, you should include the data to your question, not just print of it's part. Also session info would be useful.

Comment: Hi jangorecki, you are right sorry, next time I will be more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

The following compares the speed of the two approaches suggested in the two comments above with the following approach.

```
setkey(DT,Sequence,Parameter,Experiment)
DT[unique(DT[,.(Experiment,Sequence,Parameter)]),mult = "first"]
```

First I generate a data.table with 50 million rows.

```
Sequ  <-   c("AAAA","BBBB","CCCC","DDDD","EEEE","FFFF","GGGG","HHHH","IIII","JJJJ")
DT <- as.data.table(cbind(Experiment = sample(1:2000,50000000,replace = TRUE),Parameter = sample(1:9,50000000,replace = TRUE),
 Sequence = sample(Sequ,10,replace = TRUE) ))

DT[,Time := sample(1:60,.N,replace = TRUE)]
setkey(DT,NULL)

start1 <- Sys.time()
DT[, head(.SD,1), by = .(Sequence, Parameter, Experiment)]
end1 <- Sys.time()

start2 <- Sys.time()
DT[, .SD[1], by = .(Sequence, Parameter, Experiment)]
end2 <- Sys.time()

start3 <- Sys.time()
setkey(DT,Sequence,Parameter,Experiment)
DT[unique(DT[,.(Experiment,Sequence,Parameter)]),mult = "first"]
end3 <- Sys.time()
paste("Time 1 = ",t1 <- end1 - start1,sep ="")
```

"Time 1 = 5.45559597015381"

```
paste("Time 2 = ",t2 <- end2 - start2,sep ="")
```

"Time 2 = 3.54731583595276"

```
paste("Time 3 = ",t3 <- end3 - start3,sep ="")
```

"Time 3 = 10.0164358615875"

Comment: solutions from the comment should be faster than yours

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because it can be difficult for the original poster (or future readers) to understand the logic behind them.  Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. Thanks!  (This note is copied from another user...)

Comment: @jangorecki I don't think so. I've edited my solution to demonstrate.

Comment: @HywelMJ if you want to compare timings you should include `setkey`

Comment: @jangorecki OK: including setkey just for my solution means timings increase by 5%, 15% and 50% - but that still means my solution takes only 0.374566078186035, i.e. still twice as fast as the 2nd solution.

Comment: @jangorecki I've spotted however that my creation of DT left it with a key (Experiment). This was to solution 1's advantage. I've amended the code now. However, the DT I created didn't include a character variable. I've changed that too now. Now, with bigger data tables I agree with you: the first two solutions are quicker, the second being the fastest.

Comment: @HywelMJ I've posted benchmark as separate answer, while you answer is faster on 1.9.6 version it seems to be not correct for the data you produced. Once OP will add his dataset I may update my answer. Anyway 1.9.7 timings shows the right direction.

Comment: @jangorecki Fascinating. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

If you have data.table 1.9.6 use

```
DT[, .SD[1L], by = .(Sequence, Parameter, Experiment)]
```

If you are on 1.9.7+ you can also use

```
DT[, head(.SD,1L), by = .(Sequence, Parameter, Experiment)]
```

**Some benchmarks**

Below benchmarks on 1e6 and 1e7. Also the dev version of data.table is tested as the optimization of `head(.SD, 1)` was introduced recently.
I've used the dataset produced by @HywelMJ but it seems to not reflect the OP dataset in terms of order of `Time` column, so the data are unordered. Once OP will provide reproducible example I may update the timings.
Due to different ordering and `mult="first"` used in HywelMJ answer the results are different. I assume (looking at the print of OP data) the Jaap and nicola answers are correct ones.

```
# 1e6 - data.table 1.9.6 ----

# install.packages("data.table")
packageVersion("data.table")
#[1] ‘1.9.6’
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(cbind(Experiment = round(runif(1000000,min = 1, max = 2000)),Parameter = round(runif(1000000,min = 1,max = 9))))
DT[,Sequence:= seq_len(.N),keyby = Experiment]
DT[,Time := sample(1:60,.N,replace = TRUE)]
DT.backup = DT[sample(nrow(DT))] # ensure random order

DT = copy(DT.backup)
system.time(
    r.head <- DT[, head(.SD,1L), by = .(Sequence, Parameter, Experiment)]
)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  8.420   0.000   8.408 

DT = copy(DT.backup)
system.time(
    r.sd1 <- DT[, .SD[1L], by = .(Sequence, Parameter, Experiment)]
)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.664   0.000   0.664 

DT = copy(DT.backup)
system.time({
    setkey(DT,Sequence,Parameter,Experiment)
    r.join <- DT[unique(DT[,.(Experiment,Sequence,Parameter)]),mult = "first"]
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.332   0.000   0.331

all.equal(r.head, r.sd1)
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(r.head[order(Sequence,Parameter,Experiment), .(Sequence,Parameter,Experiment,Time)],
          r.join[order(Sequence,Parameter,Experiment), .(Sequence,Parameter,Experiment,Time)])
#[1] "Attributes: < Length mismatch: comparison on first 1 components >"

# 1e7 - data.table 1.9.6 ----

DT <- as.data.table(cbind(Experiment = round(runif(1e7,min = 1, max = 2000)),Parameter = round(runif(1e7,min = 1,max = 9))))
DT[,Sequence:= seq_len(.N),keyby = Experiment]
DT[,Time := sample(1:60,.N,replace = TRUE)]
DT.backup = DT[sample(nrow(DT))] # ensure random order

DT = copy(DT.backup)
system.time(
    r.head <- DT[, head(.SD,1L), by = .(Sequence, Parameter, Experiment)]
)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  85.848   0.064  85.829

DT = copy(DT.backup)
system.time(
    r.sd1 <- DT[, .SD[1L], by = .(Sequence, Parameter, Experiment)]
)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  7.164   0.044   7.201

DT = copy(DT.backup)
system.time({
    setkey(DT,Sequence,Parameter,Experiment)
    r.join <- DT[unique(DT[,.(Experiment,Sequence,Parameter)]),mult = "first"]
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   3.440   0.080   3.516

all.equal(r.head, r.sd1)
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(r.head[order(Sequence,Parameter,Experiment,Time), .(Sequence,Parameter,Experiment,Time)],
          r.join[order(Sequence,Parameter,Experiment,Time), .(Sequence,Parameter,Experiment,Time)])
#[1] "Attributes: < Length mismatch: comparison on first 1 components >"

# 1e6 - data.table 1.9.7 ----

# devtools::install_github("Rdatatable/data.table")
packageVersion("data.table")
#[1] ‘1.9.7’
library(data.table)

DT <- as.data.table(cbind(Experiment = round(runif(1000000,min = 1, max = 2000)),Parameter = round(runif(1000000,min = 1,max = 9))))
DT[,Sequence:= seq_len(.N),keyby = Experiment]
DT[,Time := sample(1:60,.N,replace = TRUE)]
DT.backup = DT[sample(nrow(DT))] # ensure random order

DT = copy(DT.backup)
system.time(
    r.head <- DT[, head(.SD,1L), by = .(Sequence, Parameter, Experiment)]
)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.236   0.008   0.242

DT = copy(DT.backup)
system.time(
    r.sd1 <- DT[, .SD[1L], by = .(Sequence, Parameter, Experiment)]
)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.216   0.004   0.220 

DT = copy(DT.backup)
system.time({
    setkey(DT,Sequence,Parameter,Experiment)
    r.join <- DT[unique(DT[,.(Experiment,Sequence,Parameter)]),mult = "first"]
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.324   0.000   0.324 

all.equal(r.head, r.sd1)
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(r.head[order(Sequence,Parameter,Experiment,Time), .(Sequence,Parameter,Experiment,Time)],
          r.join[order(Sequence,Parameter,Experiment,Time), .(Sequence,Parameter,Experiment,Time)])
#[1] "Attributes: < Length mismatch: comparison on first 1 components >"

# 1e7 - data.table 1.9.7 ----

DT <- as.data.table(cbind(Experiment = round(runif(1e7,min = 1, max = 2000)),Parameter = round(runif(1e7,min = 1,max = 9))))
DT[,Sequence:= seq_len(.N),keyby = Experiment]
DT[,Time := sample(1:60,.N,replace = TRUE)]
DT.backup = DT[sample(nrow(DT))] # ensure random order

DT = copy(DT.backup)
system.time(
    r.head <- DT[, head(.SD,1L), by = .(Sequence, Parameter, Experiment)]
)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  2.676   0.056   2.732

DT = copy(DT.backup)
system.time(
    r.sd1 <- DT[, .SD[1L], by = .(Sequence, Parameter, Experiment)]
)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  2.620   0.112   2.728

DT = copy(DT.backup)
system.time({
    setkey(DT,Sequence,Parameter,Experiment)
    r.join <- DT[unique(DT[,.(Experiment,Sequence,Parameter)]),mult = "first"]
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   3.636   0.084   3.714

all.equal(r.head, r.sd1)
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(r.head[order(Sequence,Parameter,Experiment,Time), .(Sequence,Parameter,Experiment,Time)],
          r.join[order(Sequence,Parameter,Experiment,Time), .(Sequence,Parameter,Experiment,Time)])
#[1] "Attributes: < Length mismatch: comparison on first 1 components >"
```